# Are Qt .ui files processed at compile time or runtime?

Tags: qt

I am using Qt Creator. When I compile an application, are the .ui files turned into compiled code, or are they read and processed at runtime. I ask simply because I am looking at UI performance and if it is loaded at runtime I would imagine there would be some penalty to that?

Comment: Do you think that it may be processed at runtime. It would be each time you run your application. This is an overkill. Logically it must be compile time. And it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using QtCreator and not changing anything to your project, the ui file will be used to generate a header file containing the code creating the UI.

For example if your ui file is `myform.ui`, the header file generated (with the `uic` tool) will be `ui_myform.h`.

If you open it, you'll see the code creating your ui.

Comment: I don't necessarily. I see the actual form itself, but all of the widgets I have added to it are not there. There is no code to add the widgets to the form.

I see ui->setupUi(this); in the CPP file, but it still does not list each of the individual controls.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can do either — but if you haven't written any special code to load `.ui` files at runtime, it's probably compiled into C++.

Comment: Right; the usual way is for uic to generate C++ code from .ui files, and then for that C++ code to be compiled as usual.  But it is also possible to load them at runtime using the QUiLoader class.

Comment: Thanks, from Parsnips comment, I am assuming that since I use QtCreator to directly compile into a .exe, then it is getting compiled and not loaded at runtime.